# UIButton inside Table Cell doesn't segue to a View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a problem I can not solve it anywhere. I have a view controller with a table view inside it. This table view is shown some data and has a button to move on to another view controller through certain data of the line to the button. But unfortunately I can not even move on to the other view controller. Already tried using only the Storyboard, and programmatically via protocols / delegate.
Can someone help me? 
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFEJb.jpg)

Follow some code:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NumberOfRows
    }

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var Cont = 0
    for var i = indexPath.row ; i>0; i-- {
        Cont += QuantidadeCombustivel[i]
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostoTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostoTableViewCell

    if (self.NomesArray.count != 0) && (self.imagensArray.count != 0) {
        cell.NomePosto.text = self.NomesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.BandeiraPosto.imageFromUrl(self.imagensArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.distanciaLabel.text = "Distância: \(self.DistanciaArray[indexPath.row])"
        var result = ""
        for i in Cont...Cont+self.QuantidadeCombustivel[indexPath.row+1]-1 {
            result += ("\(self.NomeCombustivel[i]) : \(self.ValorCombustivel[i])\n")
        }
        cell.ListaCombustivel?.text = result;

    }


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    openMapForPlace(indexPath.row)
}
```

class PostoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var BandeiraPosto: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var NomePosto: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ListaCombustivel: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var distanciaLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var SgInfoPosto: UIButton!
```

Comment: Please share some relevant code

Comment: Easier for you to say what you want to see what I post everything . The Code is extensive ...

Comment: Your question is a little too vague for me to know what to ask for. Either add some detail or include some code. You know better than us what that code is. If you want to make it as easy as possible for us to give an answer then at least an effort to post some kind of code will help.

Comment: Question Edit: if you need more information tell me that I will provide , that in my view is enough ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell

}
```

and

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(sender.tag)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: tableView)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...
However , I've tried for that way and it did not work . Even trying to AddTarget . Simply the tool made ​​to shoot the button and move to another View Controller is not called

Comment: is your all data shown in table view? and what u have in `didSelectAtIndexPath`? what happens when u select a row?

Comment: your button outlet has to be in TableViewCell class, but action in ViewController

Comment: [aaisataev] 
When a row is selected, the user is redirected to the Apple Maps. The idea of this button is to open a new view controller and provide more information about what the user selected in the table

Comment: I already tried all possible ways ... Leaving Outlet in Table Cell and the action on the View Controller , leaving everything on the table cell , everything in view controller ... and nothing 's right!

Answer (score -2):

**Consider 2 ViewCOntrollers , the one with button let's say it as FirstVC and the destination is called as SecondVC.Check is your FirstVC embedded in Navigation Controller?.If No then firstly embed it into navigation controller.Click on FirstVC , then click on Editor tab , inside it click on embed , then embed in Navigation Controler , then Give a segue from FirstVC to SecondVC in storyboard. After that write the below code in your button action method.**

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

In the sender , you can pass your array as well.

Then write a method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      SecondVC *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
}
```

Or else you can use Below code as well
In your button action method , write the below code

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

 SecondVC* secondVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewCpntroller:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, it is inserted into the navigation controller . When I created a view controller and put their class he already updated the layout equal to navigation bar

Comment: Hello. The question is tagged "swift", please provide an answer in Swift, not in another language. Thanks!